# Button submit not working with HTTP post action, already subscribed to action in razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I have a Asp.net MVC controller class called OrdersController that has an HttpPost Action method called Create(). Then I have a View page called Create.cshtml that uses razor syntax and subscribes to the action event at the bottom of the razor page.

But whenever i press my button, nothing happens, nothing is sent to my server, no error, no loading, nothing.

Could someone take a look at my Create() Action method and my razor Create.cshtml page and tell me if I did something wrong or missed something please?

this is my create method

```
    // POST: Orders/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(OrderViewModel collection)
        {
            try
            {
                var order = new Order()
                {
                    OrderTime = DateTime.Now
                };
                order.LocationId = collection.LocationId;
                order.CustomerId = collection.CustomerId;
                order.OrderTotal = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < collection.Products.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (collection.Products[i].Checked)
                    {
                        order.OrderTotal += collection.Products[i].Price *      collection.AmountItems[i].QuantityBought;
                    }
                }
                order.Items = new List<OrderItem>();

                var orderItem = new OrderItem();

                //adding order items
                for(var i=0; i<collection.Products.Count;i++)
                {
                    if(collection.Products[i].Checked)
                    {
                        orderItem.QuantityBought =collection.AmountItems[i].QuantityBought;
                        orderItem.OrderItemNum = i;
                        orderItem.ProductId = collection.Products[i].ProductId;
                        orderItem.Price = collection.Products[i].Price;
                        order.OrderItems.Add(orderItem);
                    }
                }

                OrdRepo.AddOrder(order);
                foreach(var item in order.OrderItems)
                {
                    OrdRepo.AddOrderItem(item);
                }

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            catch
            {
               return View();
            }
        }
```

below is my razor page, i subscribe to my Create event near the bottom   of it

```
    @model HardwareStore.WebUI.Models.OrderViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create Order</h1>
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="LocationId" class="control-label">Location</label>
        <select asp-for="LocationId"
                asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Locations,"LocationId", "Name"))" class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="CustomerId" class="control-label">Customer</label>
        <select asp-for="CustomerId"
                asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Customers,"CustId", "FirstName"))" class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Products)
        <br>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Products.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Products[i].ProductId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Products[i].ProductName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Products[i].Description)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Products[i].Price)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Products[i].Checked)
            @:&nbsp;
            @Model.Products[i].ProductName
            @:&nbsp;
            @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.AmountItems[i].QuantityBought)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.AmountItems[i].OrderItemNum)
            <br />
        }
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: did you try to debugging?

Comment: I've tried setting a breakpoint at the beginning of my action method, but the action method never even gets called when i press my button. I called the action method correctly at the end of my razor page, didn't I?

Comment: A couple of things to check: **A** Check the console on your browser is there any error . **B** check your page URL is there any `#` (*If it is there remove the # and then try to submit*). **C** is there any event handler added on the parent/layout in `Javascript/jQuery` to `return false` on `click` event of `input[type="submit"]`. **D**  try running the app in a different browser(*If IE*).

Answer (score 0):

You need specific method = post to go to Post method

```
<form asp-controller="Orders" asp-action="Create" method="post">
```

Comment: Doesn't `asp.net` implement default `method="post"` for the `form` tag...?

Comment: Just have a confusion, when we use the `scaffolding` engine to create views the `Create` model is built with a syntax of form tag as:`<form asp-action="Create">`(*without any `method` tag or even a `asp-controller` tag*) with an `input[type="submit"]` which calls the `Post` method on click. So, I thought `post` was a default?